# How to get a regular rank without OLAP functions

Tags: sql, db2

I want to do regular rank rows without OLAP functions(no RANK() or sth like that). I want to create a "Top-10" list of the users with the shortes average response time. I got this query below:

```
    WITH table_avg (NICKNAME, AVG_RESPONSETIME) AS
  (SELECT r.nickname,
          AVG ((timestampdiff(32,char(timestamp(e1.date) -timestamp(e2.date)))))AS AVG_RESPONSETIME
   FROM email e1, 
        email e2, 
        address a,
        use u,
        user r
   WHERE e2.id=e1.in_reply_to
     AND e1.from=a.id
     AND a.id=u.address
     AND u.user=r.id
   GROUP BY r.nickname HAVING count(r.nickname)>=3
   ORDER BY 1 ASC,2 ASC)

SELECT a.NICKNAME,
       a.AVG_RESPONSETIME,
       count(DISTINCT b.AVG_RESPONSETIME) AS RANK
FROM table_avg a,
     table_avg b
WHERE b.AVG_RESPONSETIME<=a.AVG_RESPONSETIME
GROUP BY a.NICKNAME,
         a.AVG_RESPONSETIME HAVING count(DISTINCT b.AVG_RESPONSETIME) <=10
ORDER BY RANK ASC,
         a.NICKNAME ASC
```

The result is:

```
NICKNAME    AVG_RESPONSETIME RANK
 ----------- ---------------- ----
 cyber426                   1    1
 neo927                     1    1
 neo259                     3    2
 cypher15                   4    3
 fool28                     5    4
 cyber974                   6    5
 hacker285                  6    5
 dau719                     7    6
 trinity407                 7    6
 fool380                    8    7
 wiesel509                  8    7
 dau814                    10    8
 morpheus462               10    8
 neo517                    10    8
 drago831                  11    9
 drago861                  13   10
```

How can I get the rank to skip the number 2? It should be number 3, the result that I'd like is:

```
NICKNAME    AVG_RESPONSETIME    RANK
---------- ------------------- -----
cyber426                   1    1
neo927                     1    1
neo259                     3    3
cypher15                   4    4
fool28                     5    5
cyber974                   6    6
hacker285                  6    6
dau719                     7    8
trinity407                 7    8
fool380                    8    10
wiesel509                  8    10
```

I cannot use RANK function, this is a exercise that I should do.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: "*I cannot use RANK function, this is a exercise that I should do.*" Then perhaps you should do it instead of us?

Comment: What's your issue with OLAP functions?

Comment: I did something in [mySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe8c9/2) but perhaps you could do either `LAG()` or `LEAD()` functions in DB2.

Comment: As I said cannot use any functions otherwise this exercise became easy, only SQL code

Comment: what happens when you change `count(DISTINCT b.AVG_RESPONSETIME)` to `count(b.AVG_RESPONSETIME)`?

Comment: Hey @PeterSchuetze, I've tried this before, it make the result wrong as well. Sth like this:

> NICKNAME   AVG_RESPONSETIME RANK
> ---------- ---------------- ----
> cyber426                  1    2
> neo927                    1    2
> neo259                    3    3
> cypher15                  4    4
> fool28                    5    5
> cyber974                  6    7
> hacker285                 6    7
> dau719                    7    9
> trinity407                7    9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a complicated way to do what you wanted to do with a standard select statement. You still have to find out why it works (I know why). I don't give you the explanation, so that you need to think about it and have a chance to learn. An easier option would be to use cursors.

```
SELECT a.NICKNAME,
  a.AVG_RESPONSETIME,
  count(b.AVG_RESPONSETIME) + 1 - count(case (a.AVG_RESPONSETIME - b.AVG_RESPONSETIME) when 0 then 1 else NULL end) as rank
FROM table_avg a, table_avg b
WHERE b.AVG_RESPONSETIME<=a.AVG_RESPONSETIME
GROUP BY a.NICKNAME, a.AVG_RESPONSETIME HAVING count(b.AVG_RESPONSETIME) <=10
ORDER BY RANK ASC, a.NICKNAME ASC;
```

tested with ideone.com - http://ideone.com/9F4gFo

Comment: Thanks so much @PeterSchuetze I checked your answer it was worked well .I didn't understand what you meant with "to use cursos". What's that? And in the end let with me now I'll check it why it works like that.